# sql server: set computed value to a column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to insert a new row in a table say 'table1' with autogenerated value for a single non-primary column with a formula condition `max+1` i.e maximum value among elements of that particular column. Tell me the correct formula 
**In short**
How to compute max value in a column of int type and then how to insert new row with max=1 value to that column

Comment: You have to post the code. You may use auto (identity) column.

Comment: I need to set formula in sql server 2008 for a particular column. i.e a column with some value and i want to add 1 to max(value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to sql management studio ->rigth click on select table -> select design->then right click on your column->computed column specification->type desired formula here
**OR**
Fetch max value from the database for desired column and then add max+1 to that value and insert it to that specific column(new row containing that computed value)

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert Into table1
(autogeneratedcolumnname)
Values
((Select Max(value) + 1 From tablewithvaluecolumn))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably using `OUTPUT` clause you can achieve this..

```
INSERT INTO your_table('column1', 'column2')
OUTPUT inserted.column_to_compute
SELECT MAX(column_name) + 1 FROM your_table
```

Where `column_to_compute` is the name of column you want to hold computed values

Comment: Waqas can you please let me know the same query in LINQ to Entity terms